# First request for Google Cloud NodeJs API taking more time than subsequent requests

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, node-postgres

I have a nodejs based aplication running as a Google App Engine application. It accesses the database using node-postgres module. I have noticed the following:

- The first request that I am making from my machine (using postman) is taking longer (around 800 ms- 1.5 seconds). However, the subsequent requests that I am making are taking much lesser time (around 200 ms - 350 ms).
  I am unable to pinpoint the exact reason for this happening. It could be due to the following reasons:
- A new connection is initiated the first time I make a request to the server.
- There is some issue with the database fetching using node-postgres (But since the problem occurs only at the first instance, this is more unlikely).

I am worried about this issue because logs are showing me that almost 20% of my requests are taking around 2 seconds. When I viewed the logs for some of the time taking requests, they seemed to be instantiating a new process which was leading to the longer wait time.

What can I do to investigate further and resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using standard or flexible App Engine?

Comment: @Claudio: I am using the standard App Engine

Answer (score 1):

Your first request take more time than the others because App Engine standard has a startup time for a new instance. This time is really short, but there is. You need to add the time to set up the connection to the database. This is why you have a longer response time for the first request.

To understand better the app engine start time you can read the [Best practices for App Engine startup time doc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/best-practices-for-app-engine-startup-time-google-cloud-performance-atlas) (little bit old but I think really clear). And to perform profiling for your app engine application you can read in this [Medium public blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-and-profiling-app-engine-cold-boot-time-908431aa971d).

After this, you can set up a Stackriver dashboard to understand if your 20% of slow requests are due to the start of a new app engine instance.

Comment: thanks @Claudio. Do you know how many times the standard app engine should start in a day. Shouldn't the startup happen after fixed intervals of time?

Comment: App engine scales based on load not at fixed time. You can check how many instances are active in the app engine main page.